# C# LINQ How to get MAX of datatable column<string> WHERE value LIKE 'N01%'

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need help, how do I get MAX datatable column value where value LIKE 'N01%'

Basically, if I convert this to SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(user) FROM tblUser WHERE user LIKE 'N01%'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
string[] data = {"hello", "N01jaja", "N01ll"};

var userWithN1 = data.Where(we => we.StartsWith("N01")).Max();
```

`StartsWith` checks if the element starts with a certain string.

If there's a class then need to implement [IComparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Sample code:

```
public class TestClass : IComparable<string>
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public int CompareTo(string other) { return Value.CompareTo(other); }
}
```

Comment: i have inserted my column values into an array, when using your method to get the MAX, it returning object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = foo.tblUser.Where(u => u.user.StartsWith("N01")).Max(u => u.user));
```

Simply use a `where` statement to start your filter, use a `StartsWith` to emulate SQL's `xx%` pattern. Then use `Max` on a particular column. Though make sure `User` is something that will actually have a `Max` value.

Answer (score -1):

In LINQ, I always find it helpful to break the problem down.  Here in this case, you have a list of items, you want to narrow down that list with a WHERE clause and return the MAX of the remaining items.

**Start**

```
var myItems = db.GetMyList();
```

**WHERE with LIKE**
*Assuming User is a string variable*

```
myItems = myItems.Where(x=>x.User.StartsWith("N01"));
```

**MAX**

```
var maxItem = myItems.Max(x=>x.User);
```

**All Together**

```
var maxItem = db.GetMyList().Where(x=>x.User.StartsWith("N01")).Max(x=>x.User);
```

*edit* - Per comment below, since the search string was 'N01%', is should be starts with and not contains.

Comment: Should be a starts with, not a contains. OP had it as `N01%` not `%N01%`. But other than that, I like your break down.